# Permutational MANOVA and Mahalanobis distances in R

Tags: r, manova

In this paper

> Anderson, M.J. (2001). [A new method for non-parametric multivariate analysis of variance](http://esa.hhog.net/PDF/MUVE/6_NewMethod_MANOVA1_2.pdf). *Austral Ecology*, **26**, 32–46

I found very useful MANOVA approach that can, to some extent, cope with non-normality. I was wondering if it is possible and plausible to include Mahalanobis distances as  similarity method. In fact my question is about R [vegan](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/index.html) package function `adonis` that implements this type of MANOVA but does not allow Mahalanobis distances as similarity measure. It allows though through `designdist` function the creation of any distance measure to be used in adonis, but I totally can't deal with that syntax.

Any experiences regarding this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As one of the developers of vegan (though not the `adonis()` function) I am reasonably well-placed to comment; unfortunately, `adonis()` assumes `vegdist()` is to be used for computation of the dissimilarity matrix in the function. Changing `adonis()` wouldn't be too difficult to do so that it allows any function that returns an object of class `"dist"` to be used in place of `vegdist()` - in fact it would be trivial - but I'd need to know which function you intended to use to compute the mahalanobis distance so I could write a wrapper function and provide a modified `adonis()` here for your use. Changing the actual `adonis()` function in vegan is more involved...

In the meantime, I'll take this up with the vegan developers; there are several functions in vegan that could benefit from being generalised to allow different dissimilarity functions and some already allow this. At this point in the package's development, we should be looking at making the variously-authored functions work more similarly.

Comment: The Mahalanobis distance function I`m aiming at is the between groups one: $$ d_{m} = \sqrt{\left ( \bar{X_{i}}-\bar{X_{j}} \right )'V_{w}^{-1}\left ( \bar{X_{i}}-\bar{X_{j}} \right )} $$ with this pooled variance/covariance matrix and respective group means. This is all because after LDA the multivarite shape space gets distorted and when further constructing MANOVA on let`s say centroids for factor groups this distance can provide better insight into grouping pattern.

Comment: Ahh, if I recall correctly then, this is going to be a problem. `manhalanobis()` is provided with R for this very thing, but it doesn't produce a pair-wise dissimilarity matrix. It produces, and you equation does the same, a distance for each observation from each of the group means. You can't use this in `adonis()` as it requires a pairwise dissimilarity matrix.

Comment: @IanStuart Hmm, unless I misread the `\bar{}` over the $X_y$? If $\vec{x}_i$ and $\vec{x}_j$ are two row vectors from data matrix $X$, and $d_{ij}$ is the Mahalanobis distance between the two vectors, then $$d_{ij} = D(\vec{x}_i,\vec{x}_j) = \sqrt{(\vec{x}_i - \vec{x}_j)^{\mathrm{T}}S^{-1}(\vec{x}_i - \vec{x}_j)}$$ which is described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) that should workable. Is there an R function that you are aware of that already does this or do I need to write that too? (If the latter it will be inefficient R code.)

Comment: In fact, I derive Mahalanobis distances matrix from my LDA  model like this `model1 <- lda(varMatrix, as.factor(groupFactor))`  `meanGroup <- model1$means`(which are centroids)  `mahDist <- dist(meanGroup %*% model1$scaling)` (which is in fact distance of population centroids in LDA multivariate space and is Mahalanobis pair-wise dissimilarity matrix as any other _dist_).

Comment: Ah, well that is easy then @IanStuart just store `meanGroup %*% model1$scaling` as an object, say `Y` and then do `adonis(Y ~ group, data = mydata, method = "euclidean")`, where `mydata` is the object containing `group`. `Y` is the previously generated matrix. `dist()` does Euclidean by default and `vegdist()` knows how to do this too. See how that goes.